# block method output is generating twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I write a block method to print a list

```
def column (&block)
  if block_given?
    content_tag(:li, capture(self, &block))
  else
    content_tag(:li, "")
  end
end
```

and using it as

```
<%= data_list_for @leads, [" :10", "Age:30", "Contact:140", "Phone:140", "Email:180", "Company:100", ""] do |l| %>
    <%= l.column { |c| link_to "&nbsp;".html_safe, "leads/details/#{c.object.id}", :class=>:plus, :remote=>true } %>
    <%= l.column { |c| c.object.age } %>
    <%= l.column { |c| c.object.contact.complete_name } %>
    <%= l.column { |c| c.object.contact.phones.blank? ? "-" : c.object.contact.phones.first.phone_number } %>
    <%= l.column { |c| c.object.contact.emails.blank? ? "-" : c.object.contact.emails.first.email } %>
    <%= l.column { |c| c.object.company.title } %>
    <%= l.column do |c| %>
        <%= options_menu do |m| %>
            <%= m.item link_to 'Show', lead_path(c.object) %>
            <%= m.item link_to 'Edit', edit_lead_path(c.object) %>
            <%= m.item link_to 'New Note', "leads/#{c.object.id}/notes/new", :class=>"display-newxdoc", :id=>c.object.id %>
            <%= m.item link_to 'Create Opportunity', new_lead_opportunity_path(c.object) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Every thing is working fine. But the only problem is that `options_menu` is generating twice. Means two option_menus are there. I traced out one menu is from `l.column` command because it has proper formating of column, other is generating by its on block in the view, How can i stop it for doing twice?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `=` from the line

```
<%= options_menu do |m| %>
```

Comment: I removed that `=` but still its giving output twice.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `capture` if the block is direct (not a "view block"):

```
content_tag(:li, block.call(self))
```

Comment: I tried this, i tried every thing but still can not figure out why its giving double output.

Comment: I guess you also tried without the = in <%= data_list_for (that's for sure, block views do not use =). Can you show the code for this helper method?

Comment: Complete code is listed in this [link](https://gist.github.com/905258) and updated problem is listed in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562658/multi-level-block-method-is-generating-issue)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is now posted in the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562658/multi-level-block-method-is-generating-issue/5566126#5566126).